# Using IORef for environment of interpreter [Write yourself a Scheme in 48 hours]

Tags: haskell

In [chapter 7](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Write_Yourself_a_Scheme_in_48_Hours/Adding_Variables_and_Assignment) of the very nice [Write yourself a Scheme in 48 hours](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Write_Yourself_a_Scheme_in_48_Hours) an environment for handling variables in the interpreted language (Scheme, where variables are mutable) is introduced as

```
type Env = IORef [(String, IORef LispVal)]

-- where LispVal is a simple type representing a lisp value:
data LispVal = Atom String
             | List [LispVal]
             | DottedList [LispVal] LispVal
             | Number Integer
             | String String
             | Bool Bool
```

**non tl;dr (tl;dr below)**

There is a reason given why the `State` monad isn't a good choice (environments will get passed around and eventually need to exist 'outside' of `runState`) so `IORef` is chosen instead. However, I wondered why one wouldn't just represent as an environment with `Map String LispVal`? In my (limited) understanding about how GHC compiles our programs if we later changed a variable with `Map.insert` that shouldn't copy the entire map at all. So is the mutability of `IORef` here really needed? In other words, is it obvious that `IORef` is the way to go here? Moreover, I had the impression that `IORef` was best to be avoided if possible and a typical use case was to 'leak' values from something like a callback in a foreign framework.

I struggled to come up with a good experiment on comparing performance between the two alternatives, though. It seems that the GHC optimizes my deterministic repeated calls too well.

**tl;dr**

1. Is it that obvious to use `IORef` in the example above, both in terms of performance and other caveats (mutability, IO in code that would otherwise be pure)?
2. Is using `Map String LispVal` a bad choice here if we expect frequent changes using `insert` or `insertWith`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `Map String LispVal` is obviously better than `[(String, LispVal)]`. The only reason to use a list is tradition: Scheme interpreters are famously minimalist, and often implemented in Scheme, where the basic data structure is a pair, from which association lists can be easily built, but maps would require much more work. If you have easy access to a real map in your implementation language, use it, unless you like to pretend it's still the 1970s.
2. For the types of LispVal you have defined so far, there's no real need for any IORefs. I think the author is using IORef in preparation for handling lambdas and closures. A closure will capture an Env for its environment. If implemented as you imagine, with no IORefs, then something like

   ```
   (let ((x 1))
     (let ((f (lambda () x)))
       (set! x 2)
       (f)))
   ```

   would have to return 1, while 2 is the desired result. The interpreter needs a way for `set!` expressions to modify environments that have already been captured.

   I haven't thought super hard about whether you really need two layers of IORef for this, or whether one would be sufficient. Probably the authors of this book have, though.

Comment: There's no particular reason you can't do part 2 without an IORef - you just have to pass it around in a state-like pattern instead of a reader-like pattern. But maybe it has to do with simplifying exception handling - no need to thread updated state along with short-circuiting the flow of evaluation.

Comment: Yes, of course anything mutable can be done immutably. My point is just that using an IORef is likely for that purpose, and makes it in some sense fairly simple.

Comment: @amalloy Good points, I can totally see that using IORef makes implementing things like closures and lambdas easier. Still, I'll try to implement an interpreter without using IORef after finishing the book. It is somewhat disappointing to have IO affecting basically the entire interpreter, particularly in terms of testability.